# Compile time text in template in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, template-engine, compile-time, twirl

Is there a way to inject some constant strings into angular component's template at compile time, for example, from some configuration file.

Something like Twirl engine

```
my.component.ts
...
constStr: string = configuration.constStr; // 'Hello world!' for example
...

my.component.html
<p>@constStr</p>
```

Is it possible to convert this template to

```
<p>Hello world!</p>
```

at compile time?

Comment: You can use a string Enum to store the value

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are referring to, but we have done something similar with our app using the environments files.  The way it works for us is we have different environment.{whatever}.ts files like so:

environment.prod.ts
environment.dev.ts

We put our variables in those files and at compile time those variables can be referenced in a component by importing the environment file like this:

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
```

Note, if you run ng build --prod for example you will get the parameters from the environment.prod.ts file however if you just to an ng serve command you will get the params from the default which is just environment.ts

Once those variables are in your component you can also reference them in the template like any other component variable, ie:

```
{{myvar}}
```

Note: the environment files go in the environments folder (a sibling of the app folder)

Comment: environment files is not suitable for this case. The idea is to extract almost all text (titles, button's text etc) from template and put it into a single file or JS object, so it will be easier to maintain and easier to fix some message or button's text for developer who know nothing about template code.

Comment: I see.  What if you defined a model with default values and then pulled that model into your component so that your template could reference them.  Then all  you need to do is give the model to someone to edit the values

Comment: It won't be a compile time expression, the values of model will be invoked in run-time

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a model with default values:  you could create a model file like this:

```
export class MyModel {
  myFirstVal: any = 'Whatever you want',
  mySecondVal: any = 'Something else'
}
```

Then import that model into the class:

```
import { MyModel } from 'app/models/my-model';
```

then in your component make an instance of it:

```
export class MyComponent {
  myModel = new MyModel
}
```

Then in your template:

```
{{myModel.myFirstVal}}
```

Comment: It is not a compile time expression, the values will be invoked in run-time.